# SQL Dynamic Pivot using two pivots?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm still learning SQL (self taught) and a novice so I apologize if my code looks incorrect.

I'm trying to setup a dynamic pivot table that does the following:

1. Dynamically grabs the offers from cataloginfo and inserts the pages (wpfrom)
2. Dynamically grabs the offers again this time grabs catordpolicy from the pic704current table

If I remove either line it will work but both lines give me an error and I'm not sure the syntax or how to properly make this work. I've done some checking on what others have done but haven't found anything that works. I assume there has to be an easy way to incorporate this but I'm not knowledgeable enough to figure it out at this point.

Below is the whole code.
Any help or push in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!!

```
DECLARE @cols1  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)=''; 
DECLARE @cols2  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)=''; 
DECLARE @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX)=''; 

SELECT @cols1 = @cols1 + stuff((select ',"' + offer + '"' 

FROM catcov y join CatalogInfo z on (y.MailYear = z.mailyear) and (y.offer = z.catalog) 

WHERE z.brand = 'Seventh Avenue' 
and season_id = 'F20' 
and offer_type In('catalog', 'insert', 'kicker', 'statement insert', 'bangtail', 'onsert', 'outside ad')
ORDER BY ActiveDate, Offer for xml path('')),1,1,'')


SELECT @cols2 = @cols2 + stuff((select ',"' + offer + '"' 

FROM catcov y join CatalogInfo z on (y.MailYear = z.mailyear) and (y.offer = z.catalog) 

WHERE z.brand = 'Seventh Avenue' 
and season_id = 'F20' 
and offer_type In('catalog', 'insert', 'kicker', 'statement insert', 'bangtail', 'onsert', 'outside ad')

ORDER BY ActiveDate, Offer for xml path('')),1,1,'') 

set @query = 
'SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT DISTINCT 
CONVERT(INT, a.article) as PackNum 
,a.ARTICLENAME 
,CONVERT(INT, a.RD) as RD 
,CONVERT(INT, a.SFC) as SFC 
,a.ITEMMERCH as Merch 
,Case when a.ARTICLE = q.PackNum then ''No'' else ''Yes'' End as Unbuilt
,RIGHT(''00'' + wpfrom,3) as wpfrom
,a.EBD as Excl 
,a.PREVIOUS as Previous 
,N.catordpolicy

,b.offer as offer1
,b.offer as offer2

FROM Lago_CID_Master a join catcov b on (a.offeryear = b.mailyear) and (a.offer = b.offer) 
JOIN cataloginfo c on (b.offer = c.catalog) and (b.mailyear = c.mailyear)
JOIN pic704current N on (b.offer = N.CatID) and (b.mailyear = N.Year)
LEFT JOIN 

(SELECT packnum, catid, Page, Year, catordpolicy 
FROM PIC704Current e JOIN CatalogInfo f ON (e.CatID = f.Catalog) AND (e.Year = f.MailYear) 
WHERE LEFT(f.Brand,5) = ''Seven'' 
AND f.SeasonID = ''F20'' 
AND (f.mediaid in(''CAT Catalog'',''SCAT Sale Catalog'',''SSTF Sale Statement Stuff'',''STUF Statement Stuffer'',''PKG Package Insert'',''SPKG Sale Pkg Insert'')
)) q 
ON a.ARTICLE = q.PackNum 

WHERE LEFT(c.brand, 5) = ''Seven'' 
AND season_id = ''F20'' and offer_type In(''catalog'', ''insert'', ''kicker'', ''statement insert'', ''bangtail'', ''onsert'', ''outside ad'')) src 

pivot 
(Min(wpfrom) for Offer1 in (' + @cols1 + ')) as p1

pivot
(Max(catordpolicy) for offer2 in (' + @cols2 + ')) as p2'

execute(@query)
```

This is what I get currently:
[image: Current]

This is what I'm looking to get:
[image: Desired outcome]

Update 2:
text of data before pivot

```
Packnum Articlename           RD   SFC  Merch Unbuilt Wpfrom  ordpolicy offer   
600209  23oz. HOL COOKIES      9    29  FF    No      160                  EQ 
600209  23oz. HOL COOKIES      9    29  FF    No      160           N      EQ 
600265  36 Merry Christmas PF  5    6   FF    No      042                  DJ 
600265  36 Merry Christmas PF  5    6   FF    No      042           N      DJ
```

Update 3:
I've made some progress and updated the code to what I have now. When attempting to run this code I'm getting the following error:

```
Msg 265, Level 16, State 1, Line 37
The column name "DK " specified in the PIVOT operator conflicts with the existing column name in the PIVOT argument.
Msg 265, Level 16, State 1, Line 37
The column name "EZ " specified in the PIVOT operator conflicts with the existing column name in the PIVOT argument.
Msg 265, Level 16, State 1, Line 37
The column name "DD " specified in the PIVOT operator conflicts with the existing column name in the PIVOT argument.
Msg 265, Level 16, State 1, Line 37
The column name "DQ " specified in the PIVOT operator conflicts with the existing column name in the PIVOT argument.
Msg 265, Level 16, State 1, Line 37
The column name "EL " specified in the PIVOT operator conflicts with the existing column name in the PIVOT argument.
Msg 265, Level 16, State 1, Line 37
The column name "DH " specified in the PIVOT operator conflicts with the existing column name in the PIVOT argument.
Msg 265, Level 16, State 1, Line 37
The column name "EH " specified in the PIVOT operator conflicts with the existing column name in the PIVOT argument.
Msg 265, Level 16, State 1, Line 37
The column name "DC " specified in the PIVOT operator conflicts with the existing column name in the PIVOT argument.
Msg 265, Level 16, State 1, Line 37
The column name "DN " specified in the PIVOT operator conflicts with the existing column name in the PIVOT argument.
Msg 265, Level 16, State 1, Line 37
The column name "EG " specified in the PIVOT operator conflicts with the existing column name in the PIVOT argument.
Msg 265, Level 16, State 1, Line 37
The column name "EP " specified in the PIVOT operator conflicts with the existing column name in the PIVOT argument.
Msg 265, Level 16, State 1, Line 37
The column name "EQ " specified in the PIVOT operator conflicts with the existing column name in the PIVOT argument.
Msg 265, Level 16, State 1, Line 37
The column name "DJ " specified in the PIVOT operator conflicts with the existing column name in the PIVOT argument.
Msg 8156, Level 16, State 1, Line 37
The column 'DK ' was specified multiple times for 'p2'.
```

I get this error for every "Offer" in my data. I feel I'm close to a resolution but I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Comment: Dynamic pivots aren't an entry level thing, and often not intermediate either. They can be quite complex. You'll be better off here showing your sample data and expected results. Also, please use *appropriate* aliases for your objects. `catcov` doesn't have a single `b` in it, yet it has the alias `b`. For `CatalogInfo` , yes it has an `f` in is, but it's really not the right choice. [Bad Habits to Kick : Using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

Comment: @Larnu Hi thanks for the response. As I said I'm self taught which means I don't have the confidence in my programming as someone who is formally trained. I appreciate that you think my skill level is higher than I think it is though. At your request I added an image of what I'm getting and what I'd like to get from my code. Thanks again!

Comment: What we need to see is what you're data looks like *before* your attempt, not after. Don't forget to take the time to provide it as `text`, not as an image.

Comment: Okay I added the data before it pivots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SET NoCount ON 
DECLARE @cols1  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)=''; DECLARE @query1 AS NVARCHAR(MAX)=''; 

SELECT @cols1 = @cols1 + stuff((select ',"' + offer + '"' 
FROM catcov y join CatalogInfo z on (y.MailYear = z.mailyear) and (y.offer = z.catalog) 
WHERE z.brand = 'Seventh Avenue' and season_id = 'F20' and offer_type In('catalog', 'insert', 'kicker', 'statement insert', 'bangtail', 'onsert', 'outside ad') 
ORDER BY ActiveDate, Offer for xml path('')),1,1,'') 

set @query1 =  'SELECT * into #temp1 FROM 
(SELECT DISTINCT CONVERT(INT, a.article) as PackNumber ,a.ARTICLENAME ,CONVERT(INT, a.RD) as RD ,CONVERT(INT, a.SFC) as SFC ,a.ITEMMERCH as Merch ,Case when a.ARTICLE = q.PackNum then ''No'' else ''Yes'' End as Unbuilt ,CASE WHEN Cast(a.wpfrom as int) >=7000 then ''EOC'' WHEN Cast(a.wpfrom as int) between 700 and 800 or a.spreadname like ''%CHECK%'' then ''CHK'' WHEN a.spreadname like ''%ORDER FORM%''  or a.spreadname like ''%CTOB%'' then ''COF'' WHEN a.spreadname like ''%OFC%'' then ''OFC'' WHEN a.spreadname like ''%EXOBC%'' then ''WR'' WHEN a.spreadname like ''%IBC%'' then ''IB'' WHEN Cast(a.wpfrom as int) = 2 then ''IF'' WHEN a.spreadname like ''%OBC%'' then ''OB'' ELSE right(''00'' + a.wpfrom,3) END AS Pages 
,a.EBD as Excl ,a.PREVIOUS as Previous ,b.offer as offer 

FROM Lago_CID_Master a join catcov b on (a.offeryear = b.mailyear) and (a.offer = b.offer) JOIN cataloginfo c on (b.offer = c.catalog) and (b.mailyear = c.mailyear) JOIN pic704current N on (b.offer = N.CatID) and (b.mailyear = N.Year) 
LEFT JOIN 

(SELECT packnum, catid, Page, Year, catordpolicy FROM PIC704Current e JOIN CatalogInfo f ON (e.CatID = f.Catalog) AND (e.Year = f.MailYear) 
WHERE LEFT(f.Brand, 5) = ''Seven'' AND f.SeasonID = ''F20'' AND (f.mediaid in(''CAT Catalog'',''SCAT Sale Catalog'',''SSTF Sale Statement Stuff'',''STUF Statement Stuffer'',''PKG Package Insert'',''SPKG Sale Pkg Insert''))) q 
ON a.ARTICLE = q.PackNum 
WHERE LEFT(c.Brand, 5) = ''Seven'' AND season_id = ''F20'' and offer_type In(''catalog'', ''insert'', ''kicker'', ''statement insert'', ''bangtail'', ''onsert'', ''outside ad'')) src 
pivot (Min(src.Pages) for Offer in (' + @cols1 + ')) as p1 

SELECT * into #temp2 FROM 
(SELECT DISTINCT CONVERT(INT, a.packnum) as Article ,b.offer as offer ,a.catordpolicy 
FROM pic704current a join catcov b on (a.year = b.mailyear) and (a.catid = b.offer) JOIN cataloginfo c on (b.offer = c.catalog) and (b.mailyear = c.mailyear) Left Join 
(SELECT packnum, catid, Page, Year, catordpolicy 
FROM PIC704Current e JOIN CatalogInfo f ON (e.CatID = f.Catalog) AND (e.Year = f.MailYear) 

WHERE LEFT(f.Brand, 5) = ''Seven'' AND f.SeasonID = ''F20'' AND (f.mediaid in(''CAT Catalog'',''SCAT Sale Catalog'',''SSTF Sale Statement Stuff'',''STUF Statement Stuffer'',''PKG Package Insert'',''SPKG Sale Pkg Insert''))) nn 
ON a.packnum = nn.PackNum and a.catid = nn.catid

WHERE LEFT(c.Brand, 5) = ''Seven'' AND season_id = ''F20'' and offer_type In(''catalog'', ''insert'', ''kicker'', ''statement insert'', ''bangtail'', ''onsert'', ''outside ad'')) src2 

pivot (Max(src2.catordpolicy) for offer in (' + @cols1 + ')) as p2 
select * 
from #temp1 a 
left join #temp2 b 
on a.PackNumber = b.Article' 
execute(@query1)
```